# Lazy import in Python code

Tags: python, class

I am trying to understand how `self.module` works in this code, and especially when the `self.module` variable would *not* be `None.` After it has been set to `None` during initialization, how it can switch to not `None`?

```
class LazyImport:
    def __init__(self, module_name):
        self.module_name = module_name
        self.module = None
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.module is None:
            self.module = __import__(self.module_name)
        return getattr(self.module, name)

string = LazyImport("string")
print string.lowercase
```

Output is `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: *"how it can switch to not None"* - when you explicitly set it otherwise in `__getattr__`? The module is actually imported the first time you try to access any name from it (whether or not that name subsequently turns out to exist). Throw in some `print`s if you want to understand the actual flow better.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `string.lowercase` means `string.__getattr__('lowercase')`, i.e.  `__getattr__` in `LazyImport` gets called. The first time this method gets called `self.module` is `None` and the module will be imported. The second and each next time `self.module` will be already set and import will happen. Since we only have the name as a string, the function `__import__` is needed to import the module. Finally, `getattr(self.module, name)` retrieves `module.name` where, again, the name is a string.

So, if no attribute of `string` (instance of `LazyImport`) is ever accessed, no import of the module `string` will happen at all.